# Why is the .docx file returned from Controller corrupted?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, mime-types

I have a .NET Core 2.2 web app.  I have a Controller method that does some editing on a Word document and then returns it to the client.  However, when I try to view the returned document I get this dialog:

[image: corrupt file dialog]

I've tried a variety of approaches.  Here's part of the controller method (note the commented out earlier attempts!)

```
byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(compositeFileName);
//MemoryStream content;

//content = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
//string contentType = "application/octet-stream";
//return File(content, contentType, compositeFileName);
//return File(byteArray, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", compositeFileName);
return new FileContentResult(byteArray, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
```

Here's the javascript (from a vue.js file)

```
self.$http
    .post('/MyController/MyMethod', myData, self.IENoCacheHeaders)
    .then(function (response) {
         var blob = new Blob([response.body], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' })
         var link = document.createElement('a')
         link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
         link.download = 'test.docx'
         link.click()
```

I've looked at the contents of response.body and there's a heap of binary data in there.  I've tried swapping the MIME types (mainly using application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document and application/octet-stream but to no avail.

Does anyone have any insight into what I'm doing wrong? The file that is being streamed back to the browser (compositeFileName is the path to a .docx file on the server) is fine on the server - something is going wrong during the process of streaming it and processing it in the client.

Thanks

Edward

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to simplify my approach:

```
self.$http
.post('/MyController/MyMethod', myData, { responseType: 'blob' })
.then(function (response) {
     var link = document.createElement('a')
     link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.body)
     link.download = 'test.docx'
     link.click()
```